# Doing a git push OVER HTTPS from within a build script on Xcode server

Tags: ios, xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-server

The first thing I should mention is that I can't use ssh.

With that out of the way, if anyone can help I'll be eternally grateful.

I need to run a post-build script on my bot which creates a tag and pushes it to the remote upon build success. I've tried running it as a "post" script defined on the bot, as a "build stage" within the project build settings, and as a post-build script in the custom shared scheme I'm using for CI.  The script looks like this:

```
if [ -z "$PROJECT_DIR" ]; then
    echo "No project dir variable"
else
    cd $PROJECT_DIR;
    echo "PROJECT_DIR is $PROJECT_DIR";
    echo "Directory is $(pwd)";

    git config user.email "myself@mycompany.com"
    git config user.name "myself"
    CURRENTTAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags);
    echo "CURRENTTAG is $CURRENTTAG";
    CURRENTTAG_PRE=`echo $CURRENTTAG | awk -F "_" '{print $1}'`;
    echo "CURRENTTAG_PRE is $CURRENTTAG_PRE";
    CURRENTTAG_POST=`echo $CURRENTTAG | awk -F "_" '{print $2}'`;
    echo "CURRENTTAG_POST is $CURRENTTAG_POST";

    if [ -z "$CURRENTTAG_POST" ]; then
        echo "catastrophic failure"
        exit 0
    else
        CURRENTTAG_POST=$(($CURRENTTAG_POST + 1));
        SPACE="_";
        NEW_TAG=$CURRENTTAG_PRE$SPACE$CURRENTTAG_POST;
        echo "NEW_TAG is $NEW_TAG";
        git tag -a $NEW_TAG -m "$NEW_TAG";
        git push origin "$NEW_TAG"

        echo "New tag $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) created"
    fi
fi
```

So, the hack with the `git config` commands is there to stop git from asking the bot "Please tell me who you are".  Once the bot gets past that, though, the git push fails with the following:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myself@mygitremote.com': Device not configured
```

Can anyone offer any HTTPS-based suggestions as to how I can get past this?

Incidentally, I'm on Xcode 6.4 and Server 4.1.2.

Thanks.

EDIT: I've seen a lot of solutions out there which start out by sudoing into **_xcsbuildd**'s shell.  In Xcode Server 4.1 there is most certainly not a home directory for **_xcsbuildd**, so you can't "git config --global" anything.

Comment: Have you put a password in the `.netrc` file or somewhere else that the git push can be read from?

Comment: the problem there would be that the _xcsbuildd user that runs the scripts does not really have a $HOME or a shell.  I tried giving it a shell and it started breaking other things elsewhere.  This makes any solution based on user-level settings impossible.

Comment: note you don't need to run `git config --global` -- that's if you want to have the credentials for every repository. If you run `git config` then it will apply the changes to that repository only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem. I was trying to push changes to git remote repository from bot's pre-trigger script and each time I received:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://...': Device not configured
```

My final solution was to store credentials in the keychain for the `_xcsbuildd` user:

```
# login as a _xcsbuildd user
sudo -u _xcsbuildd /bin/bash
# store credentials in the default osx keychain
git credential-osxkeychain store https://github.com
# copy added credentials from `login` keychain to `System` keychain
```